# Login/ Registration form only allows one login per individual with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, login-script

I have made a form for school and the login and registration work great however it only allows one login per individual unless I delete the contact information. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more details, for example how are you implementing login functionality? Ideally you should provide some of your code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have a `PRIMARY KEY` which indicates to database than field for example email, can't be repeated.

Comment: So don't use a primary anywhere on the form?

Comment: This is defined in database when you create the table. Table is provided by school?

Comment: I made the table but from school direction kind of. It said I needed one primary key for the form to work. I made the ID the primary key.